# Что делать после изучения языка программирования?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Изучил С\C++, разные алгоритмы и структуры данных. Что изучать дальше, в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: А что Вы вкладываете в понятие "изучил", голубчик?

Comment: знаю чуть лучше чем на базовом уровне

Comment: @foreblack, наверное лучше переформулировать вопрос...  а вообще... "после изучения языка программирования" стоит взять **вторую** книжку по этому же языку программирования,а после прочтения понять, что нужно почитать еще... и конечно практика практика и еще раз практика!

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев, насчет книжек понятно, так и делаю. Но наступает мометнт, когда их уже бессмысленно читать. А вот с практикой непонятно. Где брать задания,какие-нибудь проекты интересные?

Comment: @foreblack c  это вообще не проблема....  Попробуйте выбрать какой нибудь крохотный OpenSource проект и **попытайтесь** для начала, просто **попытайтесь**, посмотреть на чужой код. и максимально разобраться, как, что и для чего...   попробуйте сделать свою реализацию того, что вы увидите (не передирая точ-в-точ). попробуйте сделать лучше... ну а самое главное - это чтобы вам было интересно... Если нет интереса к чужим проектам и нет своих идей - нужно ли себя мучить кучей книг?

Comment: @foreblack Вас все пытаются завести в тупик, в топтание на месте. Мой вам мудрый совет: не тратьте время на чтение книг, а научитесь писать красивое резюме! В наше время одно грамотно написанное резюме стоит десятки прочитанных книг по программированию!:)

Comment: @foreblack  Вот, кстати, можете почитать по теме мною написанное:)    http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-7-0-00000012-000-0-0-1439395327

Comment: Структуры данных (без них никак), алгоритмы (без них тоже). Это основы. Попробуйте реализовать некоторые из них в шуточной или не очень программе. Знание языка без знания алгоритмов и структур данных неизбежно приведёт к изучению алгоритмов и структур данных. Добро пожаловать в клуб любителей тавтологии. Вот для базового развития [algolist.manual.ru](http://algolist.manual.ru)

Answer (score 2):

Теперь займитесь практикой.

Устройтесь на работу, поучаствуйте в развитии OpenSource(например на GitHub,  решая [проблемы в проектах написанных на C++](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=language%3Ac%2B%2B&ref=searchresults&s=created&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)), попробуйте создать какие-то собственные проекты.

Comment: @foreblack Это вам предлагают бег по кругу! Зачем вам это? Становитесь начальником!:)

Comment: Теперь изучай Qt и лабай мобильные приложения!